# Django-Haystack - How to faceting?

Tags: django, django-haystack

I'm using Django-Haystack with ElasticSearch.

I will need to have Faceting.

The Django-Haystack documentation says:

> You generally create a unique SearchIndex for each type of Model you wish to index, though you can reuse the same SearchIndex between different models if you take care in doing so and your field names are very standardized.

My doubt is, to get faceting working I can use one index per Model or I must to create a unique index?

Comment: More details would be very useful, as your question is a bit confusing. What do your models look like and what are you trying to facet on?

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple index classes, but each of them should have the field you will be faceting on.